# Task related List Visual Force

Tags: visualforce, community, record-access-level

I´ve added the "Open activities" related list in my visual force page.

this is part of page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="leadViewController"> 

  <apex:detail subject="{!Opportunity.Id}" inlineEdit="false" showChatter="true" relatedList="false"/>
  <apex:relatedList list="Trials__r" rendered="{!NOT(agentPortalMode)}"/>
  **<apex:relatedList list="OpenActivities"/>**
```

The related list is not showed on the page for community users.

Is it related to the sharing model? Do you know how can i give access to tasks for them?

Thanks in advantage for any advice

Answer (score 2):

I have found the problem: on the profile system permission there wasn´t the permission "edit task".

[image]